# python: function with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a function which prints the common elements from two tuples which are taken by arguments.
Can you give me a track?

```
def common_elements(t1, t2):
    element = t1,t2
    for x in element:
        if x in t1 and x in t2:
            print tuple(x)
common_elements((1,2,3),(1,4,5,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your assignment of element is the issue. Element itself is a tuple, so you if statement is evaluating if a tuple is in t1, which it is not, rather than if the element itself is. Try as a way to get all the elements in the tuple:

```
element = []
element.extend(t1)
element.extend(t2)
```

Now, your if statement should work. Also your print statement is weird.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set:

```
tuple(set((1,2,3)).intersection((1,4,5,2)))
```

result:

```
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `element = t1,t2` this statement you are making tuples of the tuple. Example:-

```
>>> x=(3,4)
>>> y=(7,3)
>>> z=x,y
>>> z
((3, 4), (7, 3))
```

while calling `for x in element:` means x value will be *t1 or t2 not elements of t1 and t2*.

If x=t1 then calling if statement `x in t1 and x in t2` will check `if t1 is a element of t1` and also `if t1 is a element of t2` which can't be possible because both are tuple not tuples of tuple. So your if statement will not be called. So print will ***never*** be executed.
 Same will happen for x=t2

You can use `Counter` from `collections` for getting intersection like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter((1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5))
>>> b = Counter((4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
>>> tuple(a & b)
    (4,5)
```